# Objective C TableView Clear Json Parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, uitableview

I have working project with manually data but i want to add json parsing in my project. My codes under i think i need help. ( Must be real time parsing when new item add will be auto release if it possible )

My Table View Codes

```
- (void)scrollToLastTableViewCell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.uniqueCodes.count - 1
                                                inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                  animated:YES];
}



    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return 15;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellid=@"CustomCell";
        CustomTableViewCell *cell=(CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];;


        if(cell==nil)
        {
            cell=[[CustomTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];

        }
        cell.nameLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is cell no %d of this table",indexPath.row+1];
        cell.cellButton1.tag=101+indexPath.row;
        cell.cellButton2.tag=201+indexPath.row;
        cell.cellButton3.tag=202+indexPath.row;
        cell.cellButton4.tag=203+indexPath.row;
        cell.cellButton5.tag=204+indexPath.row;
        cell.SwipableUIView.tag=301+indexPath.row;
     [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];


        return cell;
    }
```

CustomTableViewCell.h

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *SwipableUIView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cellButton1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cellButton2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cellButton3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cellButton4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cellButton5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cellButton6;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cellButton7;

@end
```

MY Json

```
{

    "Items": [
        {
            "name": "My new name 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "My new name 2"
        },
        {
            "name": "My new name 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for everything.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i do json parsing with that codes ? Ty

Comment: "these codes" doesn't parse any thing. They are providing data to your table and configuring your table

Comment: @Alok i know question is this . I need parse codes.

Comment: have you tried any thing.  For example this is over all adictionary.
This dictionary root key is Items.
The value associated with key Items is an Array.
This array Contains three dictionaries.
Each dictionary have key "name" and different values.

Can you try it to parse now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking to parse the unique codes out of the JSON, like this:

```
NSString *jsonString = /* Your JSON String Here */;
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *serializationError;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:&serializationError];
NSMutableArray *uniqueCodes = json[@"Items"];
```